# How to make an ORB server return an IOR instead of a GIOP message?

Tags: java, corba

Call me crazy, but I'm trying to write unit tests for a legacy CORBA client. In order to mock the server I'm starting up a ORB daemon and a dummy ORB server (in separate threads). The client is configured with a nameservice URL. Originally, the service is retrieved like this:

```
String url = "localhost:1050";
String ior = getIOR(url); // first line (until '\n') returned from the URL
org.omg.CORBA.Object localObject = getORB().string_to_object(ior);
NamingContext namingService = NamingContextHelper.narrow(localObject);
```

This didn't work for me so I had to change this to:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "1050");
ORB orb = ORB.init(new String[0], props);
org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
NamingContext namingService = NamingContextHelper.narrow(objRef);
```

The difference boils down to using `string_to_object` vs `resolve_initial_references` in the working test. The question is: how can I make my dummy ORB server return the IOR (plain text) just like the client expects? Currently, instead of an IOR it returns a message in the GIOP format. Is there a switch on the server I should flip?

Comment: What does the `getIOR` function do? And what is that `str` that is the parameter of `string_to_object`?

Comment: Your CORBA client expects a real IOR so your dummy server has to provide a real IOR to the client. This can be done by creating a real CORBA server to test your client, you can't just create a text string and assume an existing CORBA client to accept that.

Comment: `getIOR` reads bytes from the URL until `\n` is encountered (first line) and creates a String from them. `str` should be `ior`, my bad, fixed in the question.

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen it is a real server, started with orb.run() and an orbd running in the background. It's dummy when it comes to object implementations. These are usually stubs returning hard-coded values. The idea is to redirect the client (using the properties) to the dummy server for the time of tests.

Comment: Ok, so it is a real server. What is the value of IOR that you get in the first snippet?

Comment: I don't know, I was never able to get it working... unless I comment out the the second line and replace it with a result of `orb.object_to_string(objRef)` from the second snippet, that is a ref like this: `IOR:00000...41a`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have here some misunderstandings. An IOR is a *reference* to a CORBA object, while a GIOP message is what you get when you ask an ORB to perform some operation on the CORBA objects it hosts.

In the first snippet, you use `localhost:1050` which is *NOT* a reference of any CORBA object (maybe just where the ORB is waiting for requests to its ojects). The second snippet works as it should because you're using the native initial references resolution that return references to CORBA Objects. After you get the reference to the naming context you can use `object_to_string` to obtain the IOR (the string represenation of the referece).

Comment: I admit I'm a noob, but if I got it right, the legacy client (the first snippet) gets the reference to the naming service by reading it (the IOR) from the provided URL. Since I cannot change the client code (the second snippet was just quick try) I thought there is something I missed while setting up the server.

Comment: Believe me, I've spent half of my life with CORBA and I haven't seen any code like the first snippet. My wild guess is that at that port, the server puts a basic TCP server that just outputs the IOR, but this is totally outside of CORBA, and has to do with the implementation of the server that hosts the CORBA objects (and perhaps that service in that given port to return the IOR per request).

Comment: I think you've pinpointed it, I was able to see an example of the URL and it looks like this `http://example.com/nameservice.ior`, which looks like a plain text file holding an IOR for the naming service. Thanks for the tip!